# Adding matching comments to a word document for every match on a list of terms

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a document with various terms, which are used throughout the document,  and their definitions.

Format: term = term definition

I want to be able to add terms and definitions to this this list and programatically add a comment which states the definition for all instances of that term in the rest of the document to have the definition on hand whilst I read the document.

For example:

[somewhere in the document].... "Term" ....[rest of paragraph]

Highlight Term and add comment with the definition from the list of terms and definitions.

I'm hoping I've explained this in sufficient details but please do let me know if you need anything else clarified. Many thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: If it's a word document the comments sit off to the right and, assuming you have a lot of terms with definitions, I think it will start to get "messy"

Comment: Actually, it looks like you could do this with hyperlinks since they have a "screentip" option https://wordribbon.tips.net/T013230_ScreenTips_without_Hyperlinks.html

Comment: Thinking through how I would do this: have a table with terms and definitions adjacent, loop through each word in the table adding a bookmark for each one, then search through whole document and add hyperlinks each time the word is foudn

Comment: thanks marcucciboy2, I'm not too fussed about it getting messy since I will use the commented version as a seperate one to the original. The screentip idea looks promising, I'll have to get my head around it but it still looks like it would be a manual process of adding them in for a large amount of terms. I have more than 100 to get through. Some way of automating this via a macro would be ideal.

Comment: any ideas on how to set up the loops? I am familar with Excel VBA coding but this would my first word macro and I wouldn't have much of a clue on how to start.

Comment: How are the terms currently listed in the document/how would you like them stored? Whether they're upfront in a table or "behind the scenes" in a macro they have to be listed out anyways

Comment: the terms are listed at the start of the document. The document is a contract so will have all definitions and terms at the start which are then referred to in the main contract. I want to be able to add the term and definition to the screentip or as a comment in each instance in the main body. I have managed to get the definitons into excel as a table, if that helps? The terms and definitions can be extracted and put behind the scenes, if required. All work will be done on a copy of the contract so mainting it's integrity is not important if it faciliates in solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a two-column table for your Terms and Definitions, you could use a macro like the following:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim strFnd As String, strTip As String, r As Long
With ActiveDocument
  For r = 2 To .Tables(1).Rows.Count
    strFnd = Split(.Tables(1).Cell(r, 1).Range.Text, vbCr)(0)
    strTip = Split(.Tables(1).Cell(r, 2).Range.Text, vbCr)(0)
    With .Range(.Tables(1).Range.End, .Range.End)
      With .Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Format = False
        .Text = strFnd
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchCase = True
        .Execute
      End With
      Do While .Find.Found
        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Duplicate, Address:=.Duplicate, ScreenTip:=strTip, TextToDisplay:=.Text
        .Start = .Hyperlinks(1).Range.End
        .Find.Execute
      Loop
    End With
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Note that the macro assumes: (a) the Terms and Definitions is the first table in the document, with a separate row for each Term and its Definition, and only terms after that table are to be checked; (b) only exact matches are to be processed (meaning plurals will be skipped); (c) the Terms are in the table's first column and do not have double quotes around them - quoted terms could be catered for, but we'd have to know whether you're using smart quotes or plain quotes; and (d) the Terms and Definitions occupy only the first paragraph in their cells.

Comment: I knew you’d come in here and clean up my mess! This is more or less the first approach I took, but there’s like 0 documentation about how the selection changes during `.Find`

Answer (score 0):

While your question mentions that you want to add a comment for each term, I think it would be cleaner to add hyperlinks instead. This should be an acceptable replacement because hyperlinks have a `ScreenTip` which displays when you mouse over a link. Therefore we just have to add the definition for each term as a ScreenTip for it to be just as accessible as a comment.

My code below will temporarily save the terms and definitions from the first table in the document as a pair and then loop over all words in the document and add a link for each term that has the definition as a ScreenTip.

If you only have the excel list of terms and their definitions, you can just paste it back over to the beginning of your contract as a table. As long as you have it set up as `[term][definition]` this should do the trick.

[Example Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4Btb.png)

[Example After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18wAE.png)

```
Sub AddDefinitionHyperlink()

    Dim defined As Object
    Set defined = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each Row In ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows

        'left cell
        Dim term As String
        term = Trim(Left(Row.Cells(1).Range.Text, Len(Row.Cells(1).Range.Text) - 2))

        'right cell
        Dim definition As String
        definition = Trim(Left(Row.Cells(2).Range.Text, Len(Row.Cells(2).Range.Text) - 2))

        'connect term and definition
        defined.Add LCase(term), definition

        If Len(term) > 0 And Len(definition) > 0 Then

            'add bookmarks for each word
            With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
                If Not .Exists(term) Then
                    .Add Range:=Row.Cells(1).Range, Name:=term
                    .DefaultSorting = wdSortByName
                    .ShowHidden = False
                End If
            End With

        End If

    Next Row

    'browse all words in the document
    For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        For Each wrd In para.Range.Words

            'check if current word has a definition (bookmark)
            If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists(wrd.Text) Then

                If wrd.Hyperlinks.count = 0 Then
                    'add mouseover definition (screentip) to current term
                    ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add _
                            Anchor:=wrd, _
                            Address:="", _
                            SubAddress:=wrd.Text, _
                            ScreenTip:=defined(LCase(wrd.Text)), _
                            TextToDisplay:=wrd.Text
                End If

            End If

        Next wrd
    Next para

End Sub
```

Comment: @macropod He says in his last comment that he has his list in excel as well